# Unable to access Angular scope inside a callback function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, callback

I am having a callback function in angular like below.

```
blob= "(function(params1, params2, this.clientCallback) {})();";
serverBundle = eval(blob); // evaluating the above received bundle file as a blob.

clientCallback() { } //unable to access any thing which is outside this block. like.. 'this', 'httpClient' etc.. 

// calling above evaluated method and passing the callback method here.
serverBundle(params1, params2, this.clientCallback);
```

trying to understand that how can I access the angular scope inside 'clientCallback()' method?

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: We need to see more of your code...

Comment: if this is angular and not angularjs, you should use `NgZone` to run inside of the scope of angular, check `run` function of `NgZone` and also, I hope that you know that eval == evil, you really need to know that the usage of eval can be a deep security hole.

Comment: Ahh! got it resolved. Just bind 'this' with callback method(this.clientCallback) while using like below. `serverBundle(params1, params2, this.clientCallback.bind(this));` Thanks for the help :) If anyone of you have angular way of doing this?

Comment: `let self = this; clientCallback() {  self.serverBundle(params1, params2, this.clientCallback); }` or use a arrow function instead of regular function  which is recommended

Comment: Hi @dlcardozo, yes. you are correct. Can you suggest any other way of evaluating a JS blob file besides using `eval()` ? Thanks for mentioning :)